# How to change layout_marginTop inside a custom Layout in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I'm begginer in android, and I'm lost.

I need to change dynamically the value of the "layout_marginTop".

the layout that I need to access is this:

```
<com.rail.title.TitleRailLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/titleRailLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/title_rails_padding_left"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/title_rails_padding_right"
android:layout_marginTop="32dp">
</com.rail.title.TitleRail>
```

The class TitleRailLayout:

```
class TitleRailLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr), EndlessRecyclerView.PaginationCallback {
  ...
```

there where you see layout_marginTop I need to put another value "if" something happens.

Someone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TitleRailLayout` you can use something like:

```
fun updateMargin(topMargin: Int){
    if (....) {
      val params: ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams = this.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
      params.topMargin = topMargin; //This value is in px
      layoutParams = params
      requestLayout()
    }
}
```